# List compreension vs ciclo for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho os seguintes segmentos de código:

```
def is_even(num):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        return True
    return False
```

1.

```
lista = range(50)
pares = [i for i in lista if is_even(i)]
# pares = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8...]
```

2.

```
lista = range(50)
pares = []
for i in lista:
    if is_even(i):
        pares.append(i)
# pares = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8...]
```

Neste caso, deve-se usar algum em detrimento de outro? Ou é indiferente? Porquê?

Comment: Depende. Sob qual aspecto?

Comment: Performance/viabilidade por ex. Neste mesmo que está apresentado. Qual escolheria? Vantagens e desvantagens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo um teste com o primeiro script:

```
def is_even(num):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        return True
    return False

lista = range(5000000)
pares = [i for i in lista if is_even(i)]
```

E com o segundo script:

```
def is_even(num):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        return True
    return False

lista = range(5000000)
pares = []
for i in lista:
    if is_even(i):
        pares.append(i)
```

Através do comando "time" (ex: `time python script.py`) e extrapolando o valor do tamanho da lista de 50 para 5000000 é possível ter um ideia de que o primeiro método é mais rápido. No entanto para apenas 50 iterações creio que se pode dizer que a diferença é marginal.

O código da primeira solução também parece mais elegante e de melhor leitura.

Comment: Obrigado. `+1` pelo comando que eu não conhecia `time python file.py`